# Time machine detected

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, comments

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485116/is-it-possible-to-decompile-this)

Screenshot of the question:

[image: image of the question linked to above]
How could this happen?

Comment: Weird. According to the tooltips, question was posted at "15:46:56Z" and the comment at "15:50:26Z" so at least that is consistent :).

Comment: I blame aggressive caching ...

Comment: I see 2 hours ago for both the Q and comment and the tool tip values jive.

Comment: The new quality system is deployed: Questions get closed as duplicate before they are even asked ...

Comment: On a more serious note: maybe related to the outage earlier today?

Comment: This usually happens when the clock on your machine is wrong, and only with the live refresh of the times done via JavaScript. It won't display like that if you refresh the page.

Comment: @animuson - I have usual Linux desktop with default system time synchronization.  My computer clock is perfect.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: "The Guide is definitive. Reality is frequently inaccurate". This also provides a smattering of a hint regarding the time machine.  :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A quick glance at [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38485116/timeline) shows that everything happened in the proper order:

[image]

It appears though that you posted a comment to that question a few minutes after the previous two comments would've been two hours old - this would've reloaded *all* of the comments, and re-rendered them with (accurate!) relative times... However, the relative time shown on the *question* only gets updated once a minute after the page has been loaded...

...and only gets updated if the page is able to establish a WebSocket connection back to the server. I'm guessing this didn't happen for you for whatever reason; thus, the times you saw were the relative age of the question at the time it was loaded, and the *current* relative ages of the comments.

Comment: Yes, this bug is hard to reproduce.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what caused this; updating...

Comment: a neat proof that you really understood the cause would be posting a comment having earlier date than your answer

Comment: @gnat - The issue is that you can only see it locally. No one else would see the earlier date but Shog so I am not sure what that would accomplish.

Comment: @TravisJ I was thinking about something like editing that little timestamp field in the database...

Comment: ok, if I wanna *make* this happen in a way that's permanent and visible to all, that's really, really easy: find an old answer and convert it to a comment on this one. But that doesn't actually demonstrate *this* problem.